# Images and Stylesheets Location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

In a Rails application - should the stylesheets and images be located under `/public/` or under `app/assets/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put them in app/assets.

They then get minimised in production by the asset pipeline - see the rails guide for (lots) more information - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Okay, thanks; so what is `/public/` then? I'm using a tutorial that asks me to put them there, and I tried moving the images to `app/assets` but they wouldn't load

Comment: How old is your tutorial?  The assets pipeline was introduced with rails 3.1 - if the tutorial is before then, then css/js was put in public.  But you'd need a serious reason to put it there now.

Personal experience would make me recommend this http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book as a tutorial.  Keeps getting updated as rails moves on, clear and very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Pipeline assets can be placed inside an application in one of three locations: app/assets, lib/assets or vendor/assets.

app/assets is for assets that are owned by the application, such as custom images, JavaScript files or stylesheets.

lib/assets is for your own libraries’ code that doesn’t really fit into the scope of the application or those libraries which are shared across applications.

vendor/assets is for assets that are owned by outside entities, such as code for JavaScript plugins and CSS frameworks.